How do you delete files from the iOS app File Manager?
I am running File Manager on iOS 17.5.1 on an iPhone XR. I don't use the cloud.
I have copied some photos from my Windows 11 laptop to File Manager on the iPhone using iTunes and a USB connection. These I have now copied to Photos and so I don't need them on File Manager any more. How can I delete them from File Manager?
I have tried the following methods, none of which work:

open File Manager, click Edit, select, look for a delete option - couldn't find one
open File Manager, open a file individually, look for a delete option - couldn't find one
on the laptop, open iTunes, go File Sharing, bring up the list of File Manager documents - no clear option to delete.


Tapping on Edit gives me a way to select files and delete them.

If it doesn‘t show for you, it might be a bug and their customer support might be able to help.
